# What's the term for two or more still images combined to create a "gif like" frozen-in-time effect?

Tags: terminology, style, stereoscopy

I'm having a hell of a time trying to remember this type of photography.

In it, there's two or more still images are taken in rapid succession (near same time) and then combined to create a "gif like" frozen-in-time effect.

I don't believe it's bullettime 360 as that's more of a complete 360 and movie like sequence rather than a few frames.

I believe it's a type of camera with two lenses or something. I really can't remember.

Comment: I figured it out.  The term is "Wigglegram" or stereograph.  :)

Comment: Just FYI, on stackexchange it's totally legit to answer your own questions. We can give you more rep by upvoting that way. Comments are more for editing notes or footnotes and can be deleted at any time.

Comment: It's totally legit to answer your own questions *by posting it as an answer*. It's never really legit for anyone to [answer a question via a comment](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871).

Answer (score 2):

I would say its a kind of Stereoscopy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy